# excel converts a string of format "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS" to a date of format "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am using python's csv module to write a list to a csv file. One of the entries in the list is a string of format `"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM"`. When i open the csv file using excel, the format of this entry is showing up as 
`"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"`. On highlighting the cell I can see the formula bar shows the true format of `"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM"`. What is excel doing here and how can i ensure the original datetime format shows up correctly in excel.

To give you some background on the problem, I am trying to export data from an oracle database in a csv format which i have to do quite frequently for analysis and review.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you look at the file in raw format (maybe in Notepad), how does the date look?

Comment: all entries look like this  **2016-07-25 15:44:17**

Comment: You need to format the cell for time and choose the correct setting. I think

Comment: Format the cell as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: Thanks for your responses but I already know how to format this in excel. I guess my question needs to be rephrased but I wanted to know was how to export the dateline string so that I don't need to open and reformat within excel every time. Maybe this is a limitation within excel and can't be done

Answer (score 0):

- select your cell(s)
- right click
- format cells
- custom
- type in [$-409]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@
- press ok

Some items may be named slightly different as I translated this from a German Excel version.